# How do I set a default directory when opening a Command Prompt on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, default-settings, prompt

I'm using Windows 10 without admin privileges.  I would like the command prompt to default to a directory when I open an instance.  I have tried setting the following environment variables for my user

```
HOMEDRIVE
HOMEPATH
```

However, when I open my command prompt, it opens to the

```
U:\
```

direcory, which is not what I set the above environment variables to.  (Above, I set them to "C:\Users\myid\Documents\projects").

What is the appropriate way to set a default directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the way to do this is as below

- Click the Windows Start button to open the Start menu.
- In the search bar, type "Command Prompt."
- Right-click on "Command Prompt" in the search results. A context menu will appear.
- Choose "Open file location" from the context menu. This will open the folder containing the "Command Prompt" shortcut.
- In the folder, you'll see a shortcut named "Command Prompt." Right-click on it and select "Properties."
- In the "Properties" window, under the "Shortcut" tab, you'll see a field labeled "Start in." This field specifies the default
  directory when you open Command Prompt from the Start menu.
- Change the "Start in" field to the directory you want as the default. For example, if you want to set it to C:\MyDirectory, enter
  C:\MyDirectory in the field.
- Click "Apply" and then "OK" to save the changes.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to set the default directory for the Command Prompt
might be this:

- Run `regedit`
- Position to the key
  `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor`
- Right-click on the right and select *New >String Value*
- Name the new item `Autorun`
- Double-click and enter as value the command `cd C:\new\default\path`
- Click OK and exit `regedit`.

The effect is immediate.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have admin privileges.

Comment: In that case, the solution is probably to create a desktop icon that runs CMD inside the right Start in folder.